# The icons in NavigationView are not displayed

Tags: java, android

[image]

I have a problem with icons, namely, they do not display, only a gray square is shown. How can I fix it?

This is my navigation_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/calculator"
        android:title="Calculator" />

    <item android:id="@+id/conventional"
        android:icon="@drawable/conventional"
        android:title="Conventional"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/scientific"
        android:icon="@drawable/scientific"
        android:title="Scientific"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/converter"
        android:title="Converter" />

    <item android:id="@+id/progammer"
        android:icon="@drawable/programmer"
        android:title="Programmer"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/currency"
        android:icon="@drawable/currency"
        android:title="Currency"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/length"
        android:icon="@drawable/length"
        android:title="Length"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/mass"
        android:icon="@drawable/mass"
        android:title="Mass"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/temperature"
        android:icon="@drawable/temperature"
        android:title="Temperature"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/speed"
        android:icon="@drawable/speed"
        android:title="Speed"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/time"
        android:icon="@drawable/time"
        android:title="Time"/>

</menu>
```

In addition, the icons are displayed correctly here, but only the gray squares are visible when I start the application ...

[image]

Comment: without the code it is quite difficult

Comment: I added more information

Comment: What kind of image are you using? PNG, JPG or something? try using a default icon if it works just for testing. If it works then problem is with your image format for the Navigation view. I doesn't support all image formats.

Comment: I used PNG, default icon works fine

Comment: I noticed one relationship, namely, I have icons working in brackets next to the name (v24) while the others do not work, what do I have to do to make the other icons eat (v24) and what does it mean?

Comment: Are you using a ItemIconTint ? The (v24) means that the file is in the folder res/drawable-v24/

Comment: No, I don't use

Answer (score 2):

Well, It's a very good practice to use `.svg` drawables into the navigation view. But in your case, here is my solution. Just put one line after your `navigationview` initialization. Like this:

```
 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
 navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Hope it helps, let me know.

**EDIT :** 
Actually this line removes the effect upon your image/icon. As you saw previously, a tint layer was showing upon your image into the navigation view. When you set it null, layer removes and then your image shows up.

Comment: Thank youu !!! Your solution works, you could only explain to me why I encountered this problem, and why this line of code solves it?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm updating my answer. In the mean time if you fin this answer helpful, please make it as the **correct** answer. Thanks